# Let $J_n$ be the $n \times n$ matrix each of whose entries equals 1. Find the nullity and the characteristic polynomial of $J_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $J_n$ be the $n \times n$ matrix each of whose entries equals 1. Find the nullity and the characteristic polynomial of $J_n$

I got the nullity as 1 and characteristic polynomial as ($\lambda$ -1)

Can anyone please help me for the answer

Comment: If all its entries are equal to one, then it has exactly one basis element in its rows (or columns, equivalently).  That means it's rank 1.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the nullity is $n-1$ since you only need one column to span the image, so the rank is $1$ (apply the [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), $\text{rank}+\text{nullity}=n$). It follows that $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $n-1$.

It is also easy to see that an eigenvalue is $n$: take the all-ones vector $j=(1,\dots,1)$. This is an eigenvector of $J$, with multiplicity $1$ (since all multiplicities add up to $n$).

Thus the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^{n-1}(\lambda-n)$.